# I want to get all the data in gig after running nightmare.js but i keep getting gig is not defined

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I want to get all the data in gig after running nightmare.js but i keep getting gig is not defined

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
    const nightmare = Nightmare({show: true});

    nightmare
      .goto('https://www.nairaland.com/romance')
      .wait(1000)
      .evaluate(function(){
        var gig = [];
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        links.forEach(function(result){
            gig.push(result.innerHTML)
        })
        return gig;
      })
      .end()
      .then(function(result){
       gig.forEach(function(result){
        console.log(gig)
       })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('The Error is', error)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `gig = []` is in the scope of your evaluated function. It passes out of scope when that function returns.

Put it in an outer scope.  Maybe like this?

```
const gig = [];
nightmare
  .goto('https://www.nairaland.com/romance')
  .wait(1000)
  .evaluate(function(){
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    links.forEach(function(result){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable `gig` inside the scope of the function that's passed to `evaluate()`. The variable is visible to code within the function where it was declared, including other nested functions defined in that same scope, but it's not visible to code that lives in outside function scopes.

To solve this, declare the variable `var gig=[];` prior to calling `nightmare.goto(...`.

This places the variable in the outer scope where it will be visible to all of the more deeply nested functions.  Think of functions as a pane of one-way mirror glass. You can see out of the function, looking at variables in the outside world, but the outside world cannot see into your function to see its internal variables.